# Tensorflow unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow (well actually to Machine Learning), I was following 
 the code in https://github.com/seyedsaeidmasoumzadeh/Predict-next-word/blob/master/main.py,  the change i made to this code is to save the model at the end
`saver.save(sess, 'C:\\Naresh\\SpecialProject\\MachineLearning-II\\Model\\RNN_WordPrediction\\Model')`

Now I would like to use the saved model to predict the new word, however I am getting the error:

```
pred = sess.run(Prediction, feed_dict={X:x})
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Below is the code to predict the next word using the saved model, could you please help me here.

```
with tf.Session()  as sess:
  x_ip = np.array(
    [[38, 0, 1], [0, 1, 17], [1, 17, 18], [17, 18, 6], [18, 6, 19], [6, 19, 39], [19, 39, 4], [39, 4, 40],
     [4, 40, 41], [40, 41, 42], [41, 42, 43], [42, 43, 7], [43, 7, 44], [7, 44, 4], [44, 4, 45], [4, 45, 46],
     [45, 46, 47], [46, 47, 20], [47, 20, 0]])
  x = np.array(x_ip.reshape(19, 3, 1))
  model = tf.train.import_meta_graph('C:\\Naresh\\SpecialProject\\MachineLearning-II\\Model\\RNN_WordPrediction\\Model.meta')
  model.restore(sess,
tf.train.latest_checkpoint('C:\\Naresh\\SpecialProject\\MachineLearning-II\\Model\\RNN_WordPrediction\\.'))
  graph = tf.get_default_graph()
  X = tf.get_collection('input:0')
  Prediction = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prediction:0')
  pred = sess.run(Prediction, feed_dict={X:x})
  print(pred)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Your `X` is a `list` which cannot be a `dict` key. Try creating a dict with `d = {[1,2]: [3,4]}` and you'll receive the same error.

Comment: The quick fix is to change the list into a tuple, which is immutable and hence hashable.

Comment: A tuple is only hashable if its elements are hashable.

Comment: Thank you Zipa, that was spot on. Made below change and the code worked like a charm. changed X = tf.get_collection('input:0') to X = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0') to fix the error

Answer (score 0):

If `[below1]` were changed to `[below2]`, it will work well.

```
[below1]
X = tf.get_collection('input:0')

[below2]
X = tf.get_collection('input:0')[0]
```